# Bounded Function limit proof

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Let 
$
f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a bounded function and suppose 
$$g(x) =\sup_{t>x}\hspace{.2cm} f(t)\ .$$

Show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^{+}} g(x)=g(a) $ for all real $a$.

My firsts thoughts are if it is bounded it should converge to its supremum (I would have to prove that)

Comment: g(x) is a nonincreasing function. It is also bounded because f(t) is bounded. You should be able to use those facts to prove what you want.